# Iterating through two maps in c++

Tags: c++, hashmap

I would like to loop through two maps at the same time, how could I achieve this?

I have two vectors want to print both, can I do two time `(auto it : mymap)`  within one for? Something like:

```
for (auto it: mymap && auto on: secondMap)
```

is this even allowed?

I am trying to print values like `(value1, value2)` where each of the values is in a different map. The maps do not necessarily contain the exact same items but the key is an Instruction and the value is an integer, so if I have a element in the map for `value2`, then not necessarily there is a `value1` corresponding to the same key, but in that case it should be 0 which is the default integer value.

Any ideas?

Perhaps it is possible to combine two iterators, one for each map?

Kind regards,
Guus Leijsten

Comment: You can nest the two loops and achieve the same effect

Comment: No, that syntax is not valid. Your description of what you want to do is complicated and involves a bunch of information not pertinent to solving your question. Make your question more concise.

Comment: [Going X-Y here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) When you have two or more `vector`s that need to be aligned, consider using one `vector` and a data structure that bundles the data. in code, prefer `struct wrapper {int a; int b;}; vector<wrapper>` over `vector<int> a; vector<int> b;` Solves all problems with keeping a and b in lockstep and requires only one iterator.

Comment: @TankorSmash what it sound like you are suggesting is M * N loop iterations while I believe OP is after M loop iterations where M == N.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the regular for-loop for this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<int, std::string> m1, m2;

    m1.insert({15, "lala"});
    m1.insert({10, "hey!"});
    m1.insert({99, "this"}); 

    m2.insert({50, "foo"});
    m2.insert({51, "bar"});


    for(auto it_m1 = m1.cbegin(), end_m1 = m1.cend(),
        it_m2 = m2.cbegin(), end_m2 = m2.cend();
        it_m1 != end_m1 || it_m2 != end_m2;)
    {
        if(it_m1 != end_m1) {
            std::cout << "m1: " << it_m1->first << " " << it_m1->second << " | ";
            ++it_m1;
        }

        if(it_m2 != end_m2) {
            std::cout << "m2: " << it_m2->first << " " << it_m2->second << std::endl;
            ++it_m2;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that because you want to iterate over maps of different size, you have to use the `||` operator in loop condition. The direct consequence is that you cannot increment in the last part of the for-loop, as one of the iterator may be invalid at that time (and lead to a segmentation fault).
You have to check iterator validity inside the loop and increment it when it's valid, as shown in the sample above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is clear to follow, only need to be a bit careful whether it_m1 and it_m2 point to the same instruction. This will work out for me. Once again thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept my answer so that it solves the matter.